# How to run flask app with ansible

Tags: flask, ansible

I am a new ansible user and I'm trying to run my flask application. Firstly, I would like to set the 'FLASK_APP' environment variable then use the command 'flask run'. In the purpose of doing this, my ansible tasks looks like this:

```
- name: install flask with pip
  pip: name=flask
- name: set environnement
  shell: "export FLASK_APP=/var/www/main.py"
- name: start flask
  shell: "flask run"
```

Comment: Consider using supervisord to start your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty good article on that subject. You just have to follow it and then you could run a flask application with ansible. here is the link : https://www.kevinlondon.com/2016/09/19/devops-from-scratch-pt-1.html

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the environment for a single task:
tasks:

```
- name: install flask with pip
  pip: name=flask
- name: start flask
  shell: "flask run"
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: /var/www/main.py
```

You can also use it at a play level:

```
- hosts: testhost

  roles:
     - php
     - nginx

  environment:
    http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

Documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still not working. Your answer is good for the environment variable but when the command 'flask run' is launched ansible doesn't run the server in background so the task is blocked.

Comment: What do you mean with "ansible doesn't run the server in background so the task is blocked"?  Could you detail, paste the complete playbook and paste the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like any of the above answers, so I will post my solution.
The one shown by [@matias-burni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827271/matias-burni) is not bad, but when ansible runs this command (for the first time), it will "freeze", no following task will be executed and no play recap will be shown. If you have a flask running, the ansible will print an error and exit. Obviously, this is not desired, but I came up with the following : I recommend installing [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/), which works not only for NodeJS, but also for Python, and allows to run the app in the background. The code looks as follows:

```
    - name: Install nodejs
      shell:  |
        curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
        sudo yum -y install nodejs
    - name: Install PM2
      shell: sudo npm install pm2@latest -g
    - name: check if flask app runs 
      shell: sudo netstat -tulnp | grep :5000
      register: flask_status  
    - name: start flask
      shell: sudo pm2 start your_app.py --interpreter python3
      failed_when: flask_status == 0
```

Starting from the top, the NodeJS binary is downloaded and run, so the NodeJS can be installed with yum,as it is necessary to setup pm2 with npm. I also check if the flask runs by checking grepping port 5000. The state is registered in flask_status. If it is not 0 (flask is not running), then flask can be started with pm2, otherwise this step is skipped (as flask is already running). The same trick with registering state can be used when downloading NodeJS binary and installing pm2, so it won't be executed each time the ansible is run.

---

**Important!**
If you use python3, you need to specify it with `--interpreter python3` in `sudo pm2 start notes_mysql.py --interpreter python3`, otherwise it won't work.